# Insert image to local SQL Server database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want to add image from `FileUpload` to a local SQL Server database in ASP.NET.

I have read many same questions, but they didn't help me:(

```
int length = FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
byte[] picSize = new byte[length];

HttpPostedFile uplImage= FileUpload.PostedFile;

uplImage.InputStream.Read(picSize, 0, length);

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table] (Name, Picture) values (@Name, @Picture)", con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextName.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", picSize);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

So if I simply add column `Name` - all okay. But when I want also add image to database there is mistake:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Picture'.

In my local database `Picture` have an `image` type. Please help me.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: `image` will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch [**SqlException**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and then handle it:

```
int length = FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
byte[] picSize = new byte[length];
HttpPostedFile uplImage= FileUpload.PostedFile;
uplImage.InputStream.Read(picSize, 0, length);

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table] (Name, Picture) values (@Name, @Picture)", con);
    try
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", picSize);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
        {
            errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
                "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());
    }
}
```